# Create a simple "reply comment" button

Tags: javascript, forms, comments

I need to do the following: every comment have a reply button with a specific ID number, how can I append this ID to the form action link so that the code will change from

```
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/comments/add_comment/1/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/comments/add_comment/1/TheID" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and than focus on the textarea?

this is the code of the button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{$comment->ID}" class="profile_comment_reply_button">reply</a>
```

Comment: There is not enough context to answer this question.

Comment: could you tell me that other information is needed so I add them?

Comment: The HTML for the reply button would be helpful.

Comment: I added it, maybe "button" was an ambiguous description of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQuery:

```
var id = yourid;
var action = $("getyourform").attr("action"); //action without id
$("getyourform").attr("action",action+id); //add id to action
$("getyourform").children(input).focus(); //focus your input field
```